# Multiple Excel dates are date filterable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Looking for a way to highlight or list all the column names that are date filterable (see images below).  I can have several excel files and some of the dates are not date filterable and I need to be able to quickly see the ones that are and aren't date filterable as a time saver technique.  I'd also like to create a macro button and add it to excel to be able to do this or add it if it already exists.

Tried to create an existing conditional formatting like this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/).  But not having success with Column Header on the type of filter being detected.  There is a dates occurring.  But its doesn't detect if its a filterable date and the options are too limited.

The solution I'd prefer to be a combination of excel formulas, but a vba script would also work.  It could also be an advanced menu option but I don't think one exists.  It may require the creation of a custom menu button.

### > Date Filterable:

[image: Date Filterable]

### > Not Date Filterable

[image: Not Date Filterable]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If a column of values that look like dates are 'date-filterable' then they are actually dates and not text-that-looks-like-a-date. Excel recognizes these on the worksheet as numbers so `=ISNUMBER(A2)` will be TRUE. `=TYPE(A2` will also return 1 which designated it as a number. You can get more complicated than that but it really is all that you should require. Visually, true dates are right-aligned in a cell (by default) as numbers are. Text is left-aligned.

In VBA the `IsNumeric(Range("A2"))` equates to pretty much the same thing but you also have the option of `IsDate(Range("A2"))` which attempts to determine whether the value is not only numeric but also holds locale information that confirms it as a date-type value.

Comment: Ahhh ok.  I was using Type on the column name and that gives me a 2.  But the actual date below the column name gives me a 1 on only the date filterable dates.   But the type on the non filterable dates is set to text... which I can't control.